# Windows 10 stuck in a loop on Restarting screen everytime, clicking goes all black with cursor

Tags: windows-10, reboot, infinite-loop

After a Windows 10 update, my computer, every time I restart, will stay in a restarting loop. It will never change. It will stay like this for days, animating.

[Restarting Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mef5c.png)

Oddly, if I ever click, it goes to a black screen with the cursor.

[Black w cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8AYq.jpg)

It never restarts. It stays saying "restarting". I have to force power it off, *every day*

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you can enter safe mode. If you can enter the safe mode, uninstall the update which you installed before.
If you cannot, please use a windows 10 installation media and enter the windows Recovery mode, then start the command line. Try the following to uninstall the update and check if the issue disappeared.
1. Command line console will pop up and enter below commands
2. X:\sources> dism /image:C:\ /get-packages > C:\PackagesList.txt
3. Open file C:\PackagesList.txt from notepad
4. Search “2953522(the number of the update which you installed before)” from notepad and copy the Package Identity (Package Identity may not be same in different PC)
5. X:\sources> dism /image:C:\ /remove-package /PackageName:
6. X:\sources> del /get-packages > C:\PackagesList.txt
7. X:\sources> cd C:\windows\system32\codeintegrity
8. C:\windows\system32\codeintegrity> del bootcat.cache
9. Reboot PC